# jsTree can't find node by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have no trouble getting the jsTree to implement on the page.

I tried SO MANY different things from so many suggestions on various sites.

```
$('#myTree').jstree({
....
})
.on('loaded.jstree', function (e, dta) {
    var t = $('#myTree').jstree(true);
    var n = t.get_node("myIDstring");
    console.log(t);
    console.log(n);
});
```

My last attempt before this post was to try using the .on(loaded.jstree) callback as shown above.  But it didn't make any difference from where I tried to get the node.  Always the same result.

console.log(t) proves I have a tree.  In this case I see I have a cnt of children = 217.

"myIDstring" is cut-and-pasted from the id attribute of one of the nodes I drilled down on in the javascript console of the console.log(t) echo.

console.log(n); only echos 'false'.

If I try t.find() I get find() is not a function error in the console.

van n = $('#myTree').jstree(true).get_node("myIDstring");
fails just the same as var n = t.get_node();

Thanks.

PS: Yes. I know I could just as well us the value of dta.  But my goal is to not use this code from inside the .no('loaded.jstree')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loaded.jstree` is fired when you just have the root node loaded. Better use `ready.jstree` event like below. Also check demo - [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/tnp3k6zj/)

```
$('#myTree')
.jstree({
    ...
})
.on('ready.jstree', function(){     
    var t = $('#myTree').jstree(true);
    var n = t.get_node("myIDstring");
    console.log(t);
    console.log(n);
}
```

Comment: Once I see it it makes sense